# Express+PostgreSQL backend: Where to check correctness of data?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, express, rest

I'm developing a REST API with Node/Express and PostgreSQL as backend. Some of the endpoints to insert data to the database are a bit more elaborate in the sense that they insert items in multiple tables. I therefore have written stored procedures or functions to wrap all statements. For example, a stored procedure might look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_doc(_type VARCHAR, _level SMALLINT, _items TEXT[], _verfied BOOLEAN[]) AS $$
DECLARE
    …
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO docs (...) VALUES (...) RETURNING id INTO new_doc_id;

    FOR i IN 1..ARRAY_LENGTH(_items, 1) LOOP
        INSERT INTO doc_items (...) VALUES (...);
    END LOOP;

END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then I have some Node/Express code that might look like:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {

    const query = {
        text: 'CALL add_doc($1::VARCHAR, $2::SMALLINT, $3::TEXT[], $4::BOOLEAN[])',
        values: [req.body.type, req.body.level, req.body.items, req.body.verified]
    }

    Postgres.getPool().query(query, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error.message);
        }
            return res.status(200).send(result.rows[0]);
    });

});
```

In principle, this works just fine. However, this currently assumes that valid data is passed to the API endpoint. I therefore would like to include integrity checks and throw an error when the data is not invalid. For example, I want to ensure that the array `_verified` contains at least one `TRUE` value, and the `_items` and `_verified` have the same lengths, among other constraints.

I now wonder where to place these checks, in the stored procedures/functions or the Node/Express code? How I currently see it:

Check in stored procedures/functions

- PRO: data constraints checked as close to data as possible; constraints are checked even when procedures/functions are called outside the API; Node/Express code stays lightweight
- CON: PL/pgSQL is not very convenient (e.g., getting the number of occurrences of a value in an array is rather cumbersome).

Check in Node/Express

- PRO: JavaScript requires much less code for most types of checks; easier to write and maintain
- CON: assumes that data is inserted, updated, and deleted only via API calls

I'm sure I missed some points for consideration here. Admittedly, I also have no idea what might be preferable regarding performance.

Comment: Both. An extra line of defense is never one too many.

Comment: Getting the number of occurrences of a value in an array in PL/pgSQL is not cumbersome actually. `select count(*) from unnest(the_array) ae where ae = the_value`.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm fair enough! I currently use `SELECT CARDINALITY(ARRAY_POSITIONS(the_array, TRUE)) INTO num_occurrences;` which is also not too bad. But it's arguably still easier with JavaScript, and there might be other check that will really be tricky with PL/pgSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I would use express-validator to check that your inputs are at least correct, then I would take the view that a check of the data must be as close as possible to the data itself so done by the DB engine.
Not sure if it helps